# Does synchronized park a concurrent thread like Lock.lock() does?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

When we call either `lock.lock()` or try to enter a `synchronized` block then our thread blocks if some other thread has already taken that lock. Now my question is, when we look at the implementation of `lock.lock()` it delegates acquiring lock to AQS which actually parks the current thread (so that it cannot be scheduled further by scheduler).

Is it the same case with `synchronized` blocking also?

I even think my thread status are also different. For example, if my thread is blocked on `synchronized` block it will be `BLOCKING` while if I have called 
`lock.lock()`, then it will be `WAITING`. Am I right?

My Concern is the difference between the below two locking strategies in aspects of `Thread.status` and performance improvement by parking instead of busy waiting

1. `ReentrantLock.lock();`
2. `synchronize { /*some code */ }`

Comment: Sorry, I reply from automatic translator. I think you should attach a sample code, this will help us to help you analyze problems. In general use synchronized, can need not lock. The lock (). In general, synchronized enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BLOCKING - is blocked on a resource, cannot be interrupted

WAITING - is blocked on a resource, but can be interrupted or notified or unparked.

As you can see WAITING is better for control from another processed.  e.g. if two threads are deadlocked you could break a lock() with an interrupt.  With a two thread using synchronized you are stuck.

The behaviour of the synchronized vs lock is very similar and the exact details change between major revisions.

My advise is to use

- synchronized for simpler code where you need thread safety but have a very low lock contention.
- use Lock where you have identified you have lock contention, or you need additional functionality like tryLock.

---

If you do

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
lock.lock();
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            lock.lockInterruptibly();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
t.start();
Thread.sleep(100);
System.out.println(t + " is " + t.getState());
lock.unlock();
```

prints

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] is WAITING
```

[Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) states

---

Thread state for a waiting thread. A thread is in the waiting state due to calling one of the following methods:

- Object.wait with no timeout
- Thread.join with no timeout
- LockSupport.park

A thread in the waiting state is waiting for another thread to perform a particular action. For example, a thread that has called Object.wait() on an object is waiting for another thread to call Object.notify() or Object.notifyAll() on that object. A thread that has called Thread.join() is waiting for a specified thread to terminate.

Comment: thanks @Peter Lawrey what about the status of thread when it blocks over lock.lock() is BLOCKING or WAITING

Comment: Good point, lock() will be BLOCKING and lockInterruptably() will be WAITING as it can be interrupted.

Comment: @PeterLawrey calling upon lock puts the thread in WAITING state also

Answer (score 4):

Calling upon `lock` or `lockInterruptibly` will put the thread in `WAITING` state:

> Thread state for a waiting thread. A thread is in the waiting state due to calling one of the following methods:
>
> - Object.wait with no timeout
> - Thread.join with no timeout
> - LockSupport.park

The following code starts four threads, first two (A,B) run the same code and lock some  monitor via the `lock` method. The other two (C,D) also run the same code, but they lock some another monitor  via the `lockInterruptibly` method:

```
public static synchronized void dumpThreadState(List<Thread> threads) {
    System.out.println("thread state dump start");
   for (Thread t: threads) {
        System.out.println(t.getName()+" "+t.getState());
    } 
   System.out.println("thread state dump end\n");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Lock anotherLock = new ReentrantLock();
    List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();
    
    Runnable first = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {                
            try {
                lock.lock();
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" processing exception "+ex.getClass().getSimpleName());                    
            }
            while (true);                
        }
    } ;
    Runnable second = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {         
            try {
                anotherLock.lockInterruptibly();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" was interrupted");
            }
            while (true); 
        }
    };
    
    threads.add(new Thread(first,"A"));
    threads.add(new Thread(first,"B"));
    threads.add(new Thread(second,"C"));
    threads.add(new Thread(second,"D"));
           
    
    dumpThreadState(threads);
    
    for (Thread t: threads) {
        t.start();
    }
    
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    
    dumpThreadState(threads);
    
    System.out.println("interrupting " + threads.get(1).getName());
    threads.get(1).interrupt();
     
    dumpThreadState(threads);
    
    System.out.println("interrupting " + threads.get(3).getName());
    threads.get(3).interrupt();
    
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    dumpThreadState(threads);
    
    for (Thread t: threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
thread state dump start
A NEW
B NEW
C NEW
D NEW
thread state dump end

thread state dump start
A RUNNABLE
B WAITING
C RUNNABLE
D WAITING
thread state dump end

interrupting B
thread state dump start
A RUNNABLE
B WAITING
C RUNNABLE
D WAITING
thread state dump end

interrupting D
D was interrupted
thread state dump start
A RUNNABLE
B WAITING
C RUNNABLE
D RUNNABLE
thread state dump end
```

As it can be seen the thread locked via the `lock` method can not be interrupted, while thread locked with `lockInterruptibly` can.

In the other example three threads are started, the first two (A,B) run the same code and lock upon the same monitor via the `synchronized` block. The third thread locks on another monitor but waits via the `wait` method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Object lock = new Object();
    final Object anotherLock = new Object();
    
    List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();
    
    Runnable first = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) {
                while (true);
            }
        }
    } ;
    Runnable second = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {         
            synchronized(anotherLock) {
                try {
                    anotherLock.wait();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    threads.add(new Thread(first,"A"));
    threads.add(new Thread(first,"B"));
    threads.add(new Thread(second,"C"));
    
    dumpThreadState(threads);
    
    for (Thread t: threads) {
        t.start();
    }
    
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    
    dumpThreadState(threads);
    
    for (Thread t: threads) {
        t.join();
    }
    
}
```

It outputs:

```
thread state dump start
A NEW
B NEW
C NEW
thread state dump end
thread state dump start
A RUNNABLE
B BLOCKED
C WAITING
thread state dump end
```

Thread C ended up in `WAITING` state while thread B ended up in `BLOCKING` state:

> Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor lock. A thread in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to enter a synchronized block/method or reenter a synchronized block/method after calling Object.wait.

EDIT:

Here is a real nice [UML diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-6-thread-state-machine-diagram-example.html) of thread states.

Answer (score 3):

Parking a thread and synchronized blocking are very different. When you try and enter a synchronized block, you are explicitly attempting to acquire a monitor on an object instance. If you can not acquire the monitor, your thread will go into the BLOCKING state until the monitor is available. Parking is more similar to the `Object.wait()` method in that the code knows that it can't continue until some other condition becomes true. There's no sense in blocking here because it would be fruitless because my condition for continuing on is currently true. At this point I go into the WAITING or TIMED_WAITING (depends on how the wait is issued) state until I am notified (via something like `notify()`, `notifyAll()` or `unpark()`). Once my condition becomes true I come out if my wait state and then probably attempt to acquire monitors and go into BLOCKING if I need them. If I get my monitors, I go into RUNNING and continue on my merry way

So waiting is really about knowing that I can't do something and having some other thread notify me when it thinks I can. It can lead to blocking after I wake up though. Blocking is just competing for access to a monitor without an explicit other prerequisite condition.

When `lock()` is called on a `Lock` instance, the calling thread is actually put into a wait state and is not blocking.  The benefit here is that this wait state can be interrupted and this helps to avoid deadlocks.  With something like the `Lock` class, you have a bunch of options on desired waiting behaviors via `tryLock()`, `tryLock(long,TimeUnit)`, `lock()` and `lockInterruptibly()`.  You can specify things like how long you want to wait and if you can be interrupted via which method you call.  With `synchronized` code, you don't have such options.  You're blocking and you're stuck blocking until some thread gives up the monitor you want and if it never does, you are deadlocked.  That's why since Java 5 and the `concurrent` package, you should avoid using the `synchronized` keyword and instead try and implement similar semantics with things like `Lock` and `Condition`.

Comment: thanks @cmbaxter, actually what i am trying to ask is that thread actually goes to parking when it calls Reentrantlock.lock(). Thats why my question is blocking in ReentrantLock.lock() is actually not blocking

Comment: Yes, calling `lock` will put the calling thread into the `WAITING` state if the lock is not currently available.